# Trouble installing beautifulsoup

Tags: python, terminal, installation, beautifulsoup

I have some trouble installing BeautifulSoup4 (working on OSX 10.6 with Python 3.3)
I try to solve it since a couple of hours but it does not work...
Thats how I did it:

I opened the terminal and typed

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

That worked fine without any errors.

Then I typed

```
pip install BeautifulSoup4
```

which worked as well. Although it got installed into the library-folder in python 2.7.
Opening the IDLE of python I typed the following to see weather it is working or not

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

It came back with the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named 'bs4'
```

I googled already a lot but every solution that is suggested in forums does not work.
I downloaded already python 3.4, cause it comes with pip, I don't have it installed on python 3.3, but bs4 wont work with python 3.4 neither. I moved the beautifulsoup folder, which got installed in the python 2.7 folder, into the sitepackage folder of python 3.3 - did not work neither.

I tried to download the package from the website and installed it with this command

```
python setup.py install
```

as well as

```
python3 setup.py install
```

The latter gave me heaps of errormessages, all of them "Invalid Syntax" in some of the bs4 code... i.e.

```
.
...
....
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 175
except Exception, e:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

byte-compiling /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py to __init__.cpython-34.pyc
byte-compiling /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/builder/_html5lib.py to _html5lib.cpython-34.pyc
byte-compiling /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py to _htmlparser.cpython-34.pyc
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py", line 76
except (ValueError, OverflowError), e:
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
....
..
.
```

I am out of ideas....

Answer (score 0):

pip is probably being installed with python2.7.  You should explicitly invoke the setup script with python3 — `python3 get_pip.py`

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear.  First, ensure that your pip is running on python3; you can do this by `pip --version` and checking that its `python 3.3`.  Then, you can use `pip install BeautifulSoup4` and it should work.

Comment: I am not sure weather I can install pip or not cause I am not that much of a computer expert...
Since pip comes with python 4, it should work on python 4, right?

Comment: afaik, pip doesn't come with python4.  you have to install it;  directions are [here](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html)

Comment: and by python4, i mean python3.4*

Comment: Alrighty. I see what I can do... So complicated. For someone a computer was/is always a blackbox this stuff seems way beyond anything I can understand...

Comment: I run the script, it downloaded everything successfully but when I type `sudo python get-pip.py` into the terminal it gives me this message.


`christophs-macbook-2:~ christoph$ python get-pip.py
python: can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

When I search for get-pip.py there is no such file on my computer.

Comment: If anyone tumbles across this: Go to the link jjwon wrote, copy the text behind the download link into your pythonshell, save it as a python file and run it! Afterwards try to follow the instructions on the website. That did NOT work for me (see my comment above). So I run the script a second time and tried `sudo easy_install pip` which worked. Then I typed as jjwon said `pip install BeautifulSoup4` and it seems like it installed properly. What a mess, took me like 4 hrs to do that... Thanks jjwon for your help `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem today. My system is Windows 8, and I have installed Python 2.7 and Python 3.3. When under Python 3.3, `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`  caused this:

> ...Python33\lib\site-packages\bs4__init__.py, line 175, pos 29
>   except Exception, e:
>                   ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

So I uninstalled bs4 in Python 2.7 and Python 3.3. Then in Git I did:

```
pip3 install BeautifulSoup4
```

This succeeded and now everything is ok.